# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present] with TOT flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am seeing this error even when I have android:exported="true" in the code.
I have also updated to latest flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute **android:exported="true"** to your AndroidManifest.xml `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true"> … </activity>`

Comment: I have already tried this, it is not helping.

Comment: What is the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your _app/build.gradle_?

Comment: compileSdkVersion=21 and targetSdkVersion=31

Comment: set the `compileSdkVersion` to 31 
`compileSdkVersion 31`, these two fields must be equal
change it and try again

Comment: compileSdkVersion=31 and targetSdkVersion=31 and minimumSDKVersion=21, still fails